# Difference b/w creating a DeclarativeBase class vs assigning DeclarativeBase()

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

What is the difference between
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
pass
vs
Base = DeclarativeBase()

I am following the [SQLAlchemy Tutorial for declaring mapped classes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/metadata.html) when I inherit the Base class I can access the metadata and create my tables but when I assign it to Base and try to create the tables it throws an error saying
class User(Base):
TypeError: DeclarativeBase() takes no arguments

**Code for reference:**

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, relationship
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String, ForeignKey, MetaData, create_engine
from typing import List, Optional


engine = create_engine("postgresql://db_user:db_pw@localhost:5432/alembic_learning")
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

Base = DeclarativeBase()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name:Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))
    fullname:Mapped[Optional[str]]

    addresses:Mapped[List["Address"]] = relationship(back_populates="user")

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"User(id={self.id!r}, name={self.name!r}, fullname={self.fullname!r})"
    
class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = "address"

    id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    email_address:Mapped[str]
    user_id = mapped_column(ForeignKey("users.id"))

    user:Mapped[User] = relationship(back_populates="addresses")

    def __repr__(self)-> str:
        return f"Address(id={self.id!r}, email_address={self.email_address})"
    

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

Comment: There's no difference, but you probably shouldn't declate _both_ in the same module. `DeclarativeBase` exists to make it easier for teams that use type hints, as mypy and friends can find dynamic class generation challenging.